# How to know which option from my drop down list was selected with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to know which option was selected by Console.log?
And I would like to know if I could create something like:

If Mrs was selected, the button takes you to a link,
if Proof was selected, the button takes you to another link.

Everything using JavaScript.

```html
<html>
    <select id="myselect">
        <option value="1">Mr</option>
        <option value="2">Mrs</option>
        <option value="3">Ms</option>
        <option value="4">Dr</option>
        <option value="5">Prof</option>
    </select>
    <button> Here </button>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use document.getElementById("myselect").value to get the selected value from dropdwn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the URLs into the value attributes of the selectable options you can do it in a significantly shorter way:

```js
document.getElementById("myselect").addEventListener('change',function(){
  if (this.value&&confirm(`Do you really want to go to "${this.children[this.selectedIndex].textContent}"?`)) location.href="https://"+this.value;
});
```

```html
<html>
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="">please select</option>
  <option value="takeMeToMr.com">Mr</option>
  <option value="myChoiceIsMrs.com">Mrs</option>
  <option value="andMineIsMs.com">Ms</option>
  <option value="thisIsForDr.edu">Dr</option>
  <option value="google.com">Prof</option>
</select>

</html>
```

Comment: Can I put some kind of confirmation alert? When I select the value, Thanks!

Comment: document.getElementById("myselect").addEventListener('change',myfunction)
  function myfunction (){
   confirm('Are you sure?') 
                window.location = this.href; location.href="https://"+this.value
};

I tried it, but no matter where I click, "Ok", or "Cancel", I go to the link

Comment: You need to put the `confirm()` dialogue into an `if()` expression, see my modified answer.

Comment: Thank you, it worked very well, I would like to know if instead of showing the link, the name appears like, "Do you really want to go to the prof", is it possible? Thank you again

Comment: Of course is this possible - see my changed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `click` event listener on your button element.
When the user clicks the **here** element then you run the callback function that will get the myselect elements `.value` by querying the elements id attribute. Use a switch statement to set the value for the link, then do something with the link info or set other variables, etc...

EDIT: As for the link part of your question, if you are referring to linking to another page rather than to a section of the same page, then you can use
[**window.location**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location). Maybe you have a page called doctors and when they select `Dr`, then you redirect them to that doctors page, then you can use the switch to define the page, then concatenate that value on the end of your url address, either using `window.location.host` or by statically adding your url in a variable.

```js
let here = document.querySelector('button');
let myselect = document.querySelector('#myselect');
let sel = document.querySelectorAll('.sel');

function getValue() {
  let link = '';
  let id = '';
  // set links value in the switch using the selected value
  // in each case define variables for use outside of switch
  switch (myselect.value) {
    case '1':
      link = '/men';
      id= 'mr';
      break;
    case '2':
      link = '/marriedwomen';
      id= 'mrs';
      break;
    case '3':
      link = '/unmarriedwomen';
      id= 'ms';
      break;
    case '4':
      link = '/doctors';
      id= 'dr';
      break;
    case '5':
      link = '/professors';
      id= 'prof';
      break;
  }
  // if your redirecting to another page... 
  let page = `${window.location.host}${link}`;
  // or let page = `https://mywebsite.com/mypagedirectory${link}`;
  console.log(page)
  // an example of how you could use the value on the same page to a section
  // reset each hidden elements display to none
  sel.forEach(s => !s.classList.contains('none') ? s.classList.add('none') : null);
  // reveal the element with the selected values set id variable
  document.getElementById(id).classList.remove('none');
}

here.addEventListener('click', getValue);
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="1">Mr</option>
  <option value="2">Mrs</option>
  <option value="3">Ms</option>
  <option value="4">Dr</option>
  <option value="5">Prof</option>
</select>
<button> Here </button>
<p class="none sel" id="mr">This is the Mr section</p>
<p class="none sel" id="mrs">This is the Mrs section</p>
<p class="none sel" id="ms">This is the Ms section</p>
<p class="none sel" id="dr">This is the Dr section</p>
<p class="none sel" id="prof">This is the Prof section</p>

</html>
```

Comment: Great answer. The author of the question also asks how to forward to the link for certain selected values. In the `switch` statement, you could insert `window.location.replace(link)` for the relevant cases.